# License requirements for including open source software

Tags: licensing, open-source, third-party-libraries

In an open source project, a number of other open source libraries have been included to implement needed functionality, some as libraries (LGPL), and some as source code (non-LGPL). The new BSD license was selected for the project. The included open source libraries are licensed under the new BSD, MIT, Apache, and LGPL licenses, but no GPL licensed code.

How should these other open source libraries be credited?

Do all the library licenses need to be included in the main project license file?

Is it sufficient to just provide links to the project web sites in the Help->About dialog and documentation?

Is any credit *really* needed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248363/the-purpose-of-starting-an-initial-comment-with-in-javascript-and-css-files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each library that you use as a dependency should have a LICENSE file in their source code. I would just take these licenses and rename them to "LIBRARY_NAME_LICENSE" and include it with the source code.

I know licenses (like the BSD license) require that the original license be included when any source code is reused.

If you are just using these as linked libraries, I don't believe any of this is needed. But I may be wrong about this one.

Comment: Be careful, even renaming the license file could be a breach of the license terms.

Comment: @DocBrown: What do we do in such case?

Comment: @DocBrown Are you aware of such a license?